# Zend Frameworks 1.12: how to join custom subquery table without returning results

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-db-select

I need to create the following query (this is just an example) using Zend Framework 1.12 as part of a larger query:

```
SELECT `s`.* 
FROM `s`
INNER JOIN SELECT id FROM table where id = 13 AS `t`
```

Here's my attempt:

```
$query = $this->getDbTable()->select()
        ->from($this->getDbTable(), array('*'))
        ->join(array('t' => new Zend_Db_Expr('(SELECT id FROM tables where id = 13)')), array())
        ->setIntegrityCheck(false);
```

However, this is the output:

```
SELECT `students`.*, `t`.* 
FROM `students`
INNER JOIN SELECT id FROM tables where id = 13 AS `t`
```

I do not require the `t.*` from the select since the `t` table will be used in other ways within the complex query.

Do you know how not to select the `t.*` but still have the inner join using the subquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Zend_Db_Select->join` command is build of two/three parameters.

- table name (with possible alias)
- on part (ON table1.a = table2.a..)
- and the columns you want to select (if you define no parameter here, you end up selecting all the possible fields "t`.*")

In your query you are missing the last parameter. If you assign another parameter to the join (see example below) you should get only the results from the table in your `->from(...` part.

```
->join(array('t' => new Zend_Db_Expr('(SELECT id FROM tables where id = 13)')), array(), array())
```